# Information about video.MultimediaFileWriter

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have used `video.MultimediaFileWriter` to write frames from input AVI video file to an output AVI video file. After the output file is created the size of the output file is very large. I have used VideoCompressor's provided in MATLAB options. For example: for an input video size of 3.42MB after using compression techniques provided by MATLAB the output video size is 98.5MB.

Can anyone tell me how to bring the output AVI file to size of the input file?

Answer (score 0):

[The creation of videos using H.264 was added in R2012a](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/whatsnew.html). Older versions support the less efficient codecs MJPEG and DV, which probably explain your large files. However, this is not a major problem because you can recompress your videos using free tools, such as `VirtualDub` and `x264`. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx_kw8mYroM) is a tutorial.